# Measure length of line to any point along line

Tags: fme-form

I am trying to create linear referencing to point. I have a line to which I have snapped to points to (without breaking it). 
Now I want to find the distance from the start point of my lines to points snapped to it, this I struggle with.

Point 1. 45m from start of line
Point 2. 126 from start of line
etc.

Examples I have seen seem to focus on calculate distance between vertices but I just want to calculate length from start of line to point, for every point.

Does someone have an idea how this could be done?

Comment: In ArcMap I would do something like 'near', to give eacht point the attribute of the line it is resting on. After that I would convert the lines to points. You could than calculate the distance from each point to each point (that was previously a line) and from that table select the point pairs you have created with the 'near' tool. Havent tried it acutally, so it is just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

In FME it's simply a case of using the MeasureGenerator transformer. That will create a measure from the start point to that vertex:

[image]

Of course, what happens when you write the data depends on the format you are writing to. If you are writing to Shapefile (for example) set the geometry type to write measures:

[image]

For other formats you may wish to extract the measures as attributes perhaps? To do this use the MeasureExtractor transformer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and example! I will look closer at it. I tried the MeasureGenerator at one point but could not get it to work, i probably did not quite understand it. Can the points still be autonomous, in the way they are not part of the line more than being snapped to the line in the logic of accidents on a road snapped to centerline of a road?